# Table border doesn't span all around the text that I need in the table; I can't use CSS or xhtml only html 4.01

Tags: html, html-table, border

I have the border and I have the frame but the border doesn't go all the way around the table it stops at robots. How can I get it to go all the way around, again I can't use CSS or xhtml only html 4.01. I need to use headers and footers.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">                                
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>My First table File.</title>

<meta name="author" content="Ben Smith">
<meta name="description" content="introduction to HTML">
<meta name="keywords" content="html, eclasses, website builder">



</head>

 <body>
<table frame="border" rules="all">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name of search engine</th>
    <th>URL</th>
    <th>Inclusion</th>
    <th>Robots</th>
    <th>Reviewed Submissions</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td>Google</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
 </tfoot>

<tr>
  <td>Yahoo</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>Ask</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Youtube</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! that was it. I'm new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but looks like you have 5 ths in your header, but only 4 tds in the body?